# Accessing tabbed elements with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape all the currency tabs under Currency pairs on this site: https://markets.businessinsider.com/currencies. However I can only get the currency pairs that are active by default when I load the page which is US-Dollar. How can I access the rest of the items with Beautifulsoup?

Using the code below I get all the US-dollar pairs, but none of the other pairs.

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://markets.businessinsider.com/currencies")
response.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

currencyTags = soup.find_all("td", class_="table__td bold")
print(currencyTags)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with bs4 (unless you're obtaining the html with something that supports JavaScript and automated interaction with the page, like [selenium](https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/2f8ad15efe25)), but you *can* request the data from the same API that the site fetches it from<sup>(view [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDZWY.png) from [network logs](https://support.happyfox.com/kb/article/882-accessing-the-browser-console-and-network-logs/))</sup>.

---

For example, for Japanese Yen:

```py
import request
import pandas as pd

cur_tab = 'JPY' # 'MostViewed' # 'USD' # 'EUR' #
api_endpt = f'https://markets.businessinsider.com/ajax/ExchangeRate_PopularListData' 
api_data = requests.get(f'{api_endpt}?currency={cur_tab}').json()
df = pd.DataFrame(api_data['ExchangeRates'])
```

[image: opdf]

---

Or to get all of the tabs:

```py
import request
import pandas as pd

cur_tabs = ['MostViewed', 'USD', 'EUR', 'JPY']
api_endpt = 'https://markets.businessinsider.com/ajax/ExchangeRate_PopularListData'

dfList = [pd.DataFrame(
    requests.get(f'{api_endpt}?currency={cur_tab}').json()['ExchangeRates']
) for cur_tab in cur_tabs] 
df = pd.concat(dfList, keys=cur_tabs)
```

[image: opdf2]